# Limits: if $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0 $, does $\lim_{x \to 0}f(1/x)$ exist?

Tags: limits

Let $f$ be a function:
$$ f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $$
It is known that:
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0 $$
I need to prove / disprove that the following limit exist:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$

Comment: What does $x\to \infty$ mean here? Does it mean $x \to +\infty$ or $\lvert x\rvert \to \infty$?

Comment: It means $$ x \to +\infty $$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x&;x>0\\1&;x\le0\end{cases}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(1/x)=\lim_{x\to0^+}x=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}f(1/x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}1=1$$

Comment: So simple...Thank you

Comment: @Noam That is my trademark ;)

Comment: @SimpleArt For the love of simplicity, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ is an even simpler function ;)

Comment: @5xum Oh you...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the simplest counterexample would be $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

The limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} e^{-\frac1x}$$ does not exist, because if $x$ is small but positive, $e^{-\frac1x}$ is close to $0$, but if $x$ is small and negative, then $e^{-\frac1x}$ is large.